# Retrieve a part of a link in a web page with wget

Tags: shell, batch-file, hyperlink, wget

I would like to **[retrieve a specific part of a link in this web page using batch](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/list/rb/)**

Firstly, to **retrieve this web page**, I used this command :

```
wget --convert-links -N "http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/list/rb/"
```

Then, in this web page, I would like to get just this line :

```
<a href="http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/get/01844_1.4.7-R1.0/bukkit.jar" class="tooltipd" title="Download Bukkit, version 1.4.7-R1.0">
```

And after, **retrieve just the build name in the link** :

```
01844_1.4.7-R1.0
```

So, I used this :

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('grep "/downloads/bukkit/view/" index.html ^| head --lines=2') do set build=%%i
del index.html
set build=%build:~68,16%
echo %build%
```

To conclude, I retrieve what I want okay, but I think there is a another way to do it, because as you can guess it, **the build name doesn't have the same length all the time (sometimes "00718_1.1-R4" = 12 characters only for this build name)**, and **I used a "fixed" method (set build=%build:~68,16%)** to retrieve it...

So, if anyone have **a best way to do it, with a slash as delimiter maybe** ? But I don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
del index.html
FOR /f "tokens=6delims=/" %%t IN ("%build%") DO SET build=%%t
echo %build%
```

should return the string required.

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
for /f %%i in ('wget "http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/list/rb/" --output-document=- 2^>nul^|sed -n "/downloads\/bukkit\/get\//{s:.*/\([R0-9_.-]\+\).*:\1:p;q}"') do set "build=%%i"
echo %build%
```

needs no `index.html`.

Comment: Hey, thanks it works also but I can't retrieve the result of the command in a variable. I've already tried with FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('WGET "http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/list/rb/" --output-document=- 2>nul|sed -n "/downloads\/bukkit\/get\//{s:.*/\([R0-9_.-]\+\).*:\1:p;q}"') DO SET Result=%%i

Comment: I made an edit. Escape `>` and `|` with `^`.  BTW: this answer is for info only. Do not change the acceptance.

Comment: Oh perfect ! Okay for the acceptance because I would have changed otherwise. Thanks a lot :) !